# DevForce Error when Run Custom Tool

Tags: silverlight-4.0, devforce

When I right click on the T4 file and Run Custom Tool, I get the errors

Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'IdeaBlade.VisualStudio.DTE.dll' could not be found
Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'IdeaBlade.VisualStudio.OM.CodeGenerator.dll' could not be found
Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Edm.Metadata.dll' could not be found

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That error means that Visual Studio was unable to find some of the DLLs necessary to run DevForce's T4 generation.  Probably the easiest way to solve this is by running the Dev Force installer.  That will place the necessary DLLs in the GAC where Visual Studio will be able to find them.

I believe you can also add References to these specific DLLs on the project that contains your Data Model but I haven't done that because I prefer to have Dev Force installed on any machine that needs to run the T4s.